# Fat free php Captcha is showing complete black image

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

While using captcha method I am getting complete black image in linux server where as it is completely working fine in my local XAMPP environment.

I have this code in my server for a route

```
$img = new Image();
$img->captcha("PermanentMarker-Regular.ttf", 100, 6, 'SESSION.captcha_code', '', '0X369', '0XEEE');
$img->render();
unset($img);
```

I have included that font in UI folder.

this is the GD part in the php info of my server :

- GD Support enabled
- GD headers Version  2.2.5
- GD library Version    2.2.5
- FreeType Support  enabled
- FreeType Linkage  with freetype
- FreeType Version  2.8.1
- GIF Read Support  enabled
- GIF Create Support    enabled
- JPEG Support  enabled
- libJPEG Version   8
- PNG Support   enabled
- libPNG Version    1.6.34
- WBMP Support  enabled
- XPM Support   enabled
- libXpm Version    30411
- XBM Support   enabled
- WebP Support  enabled

actual image looks like this

[image: x]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You have to check if the path of the font is correct.

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer. Or you should be more precise and give more details where and how to change the code.

Comment: Hi leser, I am able to download the font if I create a route for it. But I think there is another issue which I might be facing it. I wrote a code to check whether that file exists or not but I didnt get any error.

Comment: Hi! Perhaps changing the font will work.
This one worked for me: Kinnari-BoldOblique.ttf